# While calling SQL CLR procedure getting application pool size reached to Max getting error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sqlclr

While running asp.net application which is calling stored procedure hosted in sql server with sql clr returning below error:-

```
An error occurred: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Procedure Name": 
 System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
System.InvalidOperationException: 
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at StoredProcedures.ProcedureName(String sourceConnectionString, String destinationConnectionString, String sql, String destinationTable, String columns)”
```

We are using asp.net boiler plate and entity framework.
In SQL CLR we had used ado.net and close connection by using "Using" Keyword.
So I think connection close issue should not be there.

Kindly suggest as in stored procedure we are fetching data from one source to another source by passing connection string.

Comment: Do you close your connections anywhere?

Comment: Run Code Analysis to make sure your not leaving something undisposed.

Comment: Oh, and please post a couple of code fragments where you open your connection (and close it), and call the sql.

Comment: yes I had closed connections.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you've run into usually occurs when there have been multiple connections made to a database, but never properly closed/disposed the connections after use.

• Make sure to close all connections after use. 
• You could also inherit IDisposable on you connection/procedural class. Implementing the dispose method to clear the instantiated connection after use.

See below example:

```
public partial class Connection : IDisposable
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the connection string.
    /// </summary>
    protected static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor for the Database Connection Class.
    /// </summary>
    public Connection()
    {
        this.sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString);
        this.sqlConnection.Open();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (sqlConnection != null)
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlConnection.Close();

            sqlConnection.Dispose();
            sqlConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How much time does each call to the remote instance (being done within the SQLCLR Stored Procedure) take, generally? And, generally how frequently is this Stored Procedure being called? If you really did instantiate the `SqlConnection` properly within a `using` construct (e.g. `using (SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(UserConnectionString)) { ... }`), then is there any reason to assume that the error message of "**This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.**" is misleading, or that there was a real timeout due to some network issue?

Please keep in mind that the default Connection Pool size is 100 connections. IF this code takes a second (or a few) to complete, AND IF this code is called frequently, then quite possibly you really did run out of connections in the pool. You can at least test this theory by increasing the pool size by adding the following to the connection string:

```
Max Pool Size = 200;
```

It doesn't need to be 200, but if you do try that and never get the error again, then you did run out of the default 100 connections. If you still get the error, then perhaps there is something else going on, such as either network latency OR SQL Server running out of available connections and not allowing any more in the first place.

Comment: it will take a bit time as copy stored procedure copy data from one different server to the current server where sqlclr is using stored procedure.

Comment: SQL CLR Stored procedure is calling much frequent.

Comment: @MayankJain Ok, good to know. So then I was on the right track and you need to set `Max Pool Size=200;` in the `ConnectionString`. And are you using `SqlBulkCopy` to move the data?